# Preg replace to words with hash

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all username that start with `#` in a string. I tried this

```
preg_replace('/#/', '', 'blah blah blah #key blah blah');
```

But it removes only the `#`.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your usernames not contain spaces, then this should work

```
preg_replace('/#[^\s]+/', '', 'blah blah blah #key blah blah');
```

Answer (score 3):

`/#[^\b]+/` should work fine.

Explanation of regex:

- `#` *A litteral `#` character*
- `[^\b]+` *Matches anything until a word boundary is hit*

  - `^` *means "not"*
  - `\b` *is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and will match any non-alphanumerical character (or end of string), and therefore supports "`my string #username. Another string`" to just match `#username` which is something that eg. `[^\s]+` does **not** support. (it would match it with the period)*
  - `+` *means "repeated one or more times"*

In code:

```
preg_replace('/#[^\b]+/', '', 'blah blah blah #key blah blah');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`echo preg_replace('/#\w+/', '', 'blah blah blah #key blah blah');`

output : `blah blah blah blah blah`